# interchanging limit processes

Tags: real-analysis

I am given the following problem
"Suppose that $f_n(x)$ uniformly converges to $f(x)$ on the interval $[a,b]$. Assume also that for $x_0\in (a,b)$ $\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0}f_n(x)=a_n$ for each $n$. Show that $\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0}f(x)$ exists and that $\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0}f(x)=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}a_n$. That is $\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0}\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}f_n(x)=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0}f_n(x)$"

I think I can prove this if we add the assumption that each of the $f_n$ are continuous, but the problem does not state this. Is it necessary to assume the $f_n$ are continuous, or can the statement be proved without this assumption? thanks :)

Comment: You don't need continuity. Start by showing a_n is a Cauchy sequence, hence convergent with limit, say, L. Then estimate |f(x) - L|.